Z-fighting or mesh flickering in Unity webgl while it is correct in standalone
Some meshes are flickering in WebGL while they work smoothly in the standalone application. This happens with different projects. To resolve the issue, I have to adjust the camera's near clip; sometimes it's 0.09, and sometimes it's 0.35 to solve the problem. Is there any generic way to solve this problem for every mesh, or am I missing any mesh standards?



This can happen due to different depth buffer precision available in the web renderer vs a standalone executable.
As you've found, one of the best ways to solve it is to concentrate the available precision where you need it. There are only so many distinct depth values you can store, and they need to be stretched out to cover the whole distance between the camera's near and far planes. The closer those planes are together, the tighter the spacing of your depth values, so you're less liable to stack two triangles in the same depth bucket. Pulling in the far plane to closely hug the most distant content you need to render can yield major improvements in z-fighting and shadow quality as a bonus (since more shadow map texels get allocated close to the camera where the resolution is most noticeable).
In particular, the ratio of near:far matters — the closer near is to zero, the worse your distribution of depth values gets. So pushing out the near plane as far as you can helps a lot.
Sometimes you need to render very distant geometry (like far off landmarks in an open world game, or planets in a space game) or very near geometry (like tools/weapons held in a first-person character's hands), and stretching your near-far planes to encompass the whole range murders your precision. In cases like these, you can use camera stacking: separate your content into layers for the very close / very far, and make a copy of your camera to render each with their own tailored near-far ranges. You render the most distant content first, then layer the nearer content on top, keeping the colour buffer but discarding the depth buffer between cameras. You pay more overdraw this way, but in trade you can massively extend your drawing range and precision.
Valve used this trick to draw the Citadel and distant buildings in Half-Life 2, and many FPS games use this for drawing the character's hands/tool/weapon/helmet, with the bonus that it also prevents clipping between these items and nearby geometry if you squeeze up against a wall.
These solutions are general-purpose and will reduce z-fighting with all meshes. But if it's just a few particular objects / materials that have this problem (especially ones used as decals or overlays like selection highlights), you can also apply a targeted fix-up in your shader.
The Offset command documented here allows you to shift the depth value used for testing the fragments of this material against the depth buffer — making it behave as though it were closer to the camera so it more reliably sorts in front of nearly co-planar geometry — but without shifting where it's actually drawn on screen. The units argument lets you pull or push the testing value by a fixed distance, while the factor argument augments that pull/push proportional to the slope of the triangle relative to the view direction, helping to account for the fact that you need a bigger bias when looking along a surface at a shallow angle.
